# Searching at beginning of every line

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I have a text file something like:

```
lineat2

corrupt

exitCode()
```

and so on...

Each line has some text. I want to copy those lines from this file which start with `corrupt` to another file.
Any command (`sed`/`grep`) to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep ^corrupt textfile > anotherfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/^corrupt/p' FILE > NEXTFILE
```